# CSS: Align text to an element with display inline-block

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a short text next to which I have to put a link. The link should not be visible as a text but as an image. So far no problems, however to use the image I have to set `display:inline-block` to be able to set the width/height of the tag. As soon as I do it, the next which was next to from the right jumps downwards in the containing div. I am absolutely unable to move it upwards. The code is:

```
<div>
    <p id="pid">Some prefixing text that shouldn't be at the bottom of the div but rather in the middle <a href="#" target="_blank">This is some link</a></p>
</div>

#pid {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: right;
}
#pid a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 53px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DxVQr/1/

So how could I move the prefix text upwards? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You say "The link should not be visible as a text but as an image." but you have text??

Comment: I have text to demonstrate what I am talking about. There is no need for an image in the example as it would behave exactly the same.

Comment: You could set the `inline-block` element's `vertical-align` to `middle` so that it aligns itself centered with respect to adjacent `inline` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/DxVQr/2/ The link kind of gets clipped though because the link's `height` is set too small.

Comment: I know i'm changing things up, but do you want something like.. http://jsfiddle.net/UDCRS/ ??

Comment: @JoshC Interesting solution, problem is that I cannot really position it like that other the to the center, can I?

Comment: @Fygo What if I put this as a solution? http://jsfiddle.net/UDCRS/1/

Comment: It doesn't use `vertical-align:middle`..

Comment: @JoshC Not bad either, I am upvoting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `vertical-align: middle` on the `<a>` tag does the job?

Comment: Not bad for an emergency solution. Is there any way how to align it more precisely? The image will have a shadow so the text will need to go to about 25% of image's height.

Comment: Well, I can actually set the % in vertical align so if I set it to minus, it should make the trick...

Comment: Then pull it out with a negative margin or `position: relative`.